# Rails 3.1 UJS link_to remote true have to reload page to work

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

So Ive got a link to logout that i want to use ajax to handle.

```
<li><%= link_to('Logout', "#", :method => :delete, :remote => true, :class => 'logout') %></li>
```

However there has to be a page reload every time for the logout to work and then for the partial to be rendered. Login works absolutely fine though. When the logout link is clicked without the page reload it only does a delete to localhost for some reason it will not delete to /users/sign_out. Then the page needs another reload for the $(#user_login_box) to be updated. This is on the logout only.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 function setNotice(data) {

 var $flash = $("<div>",{
  'class': 'alert alert-success',
  'html': data.data.message 
 });

var $link  = $("<a>",{
  'html': 'x',
  'class': 'close',
  'href': '#',
  'data-dismiss': 'alert'
}).data("dismiss","alert").prependTo( $flash );


$('#account').html(function(){
 return data.login ? data.email : "Account" ;
});
$('.row').prepend($flash);
$('#user_login_box').html(data.content);    
}


$('form#sign_in').bind('ajax:success', function(e, data, status, xhr) {
  console.log(data);
 if(data.success) { 
   setNotice(data)

} else {
  $('#status').html(data.data.message);

}
});

 $(".logout").on("click", function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
  $.post("/users/sign_out", {_method:"delete"}, function(data){
   setNotice(data);
  });
 });


});
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try adding your sign out path to the link. Right now it looks like the href attribute is set to a hash. From what I remember, jquery-rails uses the href attribute to determine the url for the request.